# How to flatten a nested object with Ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming, ramda.js, flatten

Is there a way using `Ramda.js` by which I can have a nested object which can have multiple properties converted to an array of arrays as mentioned in the output?

Please note that the `values` are always present in indices `3` and `4` where we have values like `21`, `4`, and so on. The output array length should map to the `input` object keys length.

```js
const input = {
  "002004": {
    "25-34 Years": {
      "Jul-20": [
        [
          "Jul-20",
          "002004",
          "002004 - No Description",
          21,
          4,
          "25-34 Years"
        ]
      ],
      "Jun-20": [
        [
          "Jun-20",
          "002004",
          "002004 - No Description",
          25,
          8,
          "25-34 Years"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "35-44 Years": {
      "Jul-20": [
        [
          "Jul-20",
          "002004",
          "002004 - No Description",
          3,
          10,
          "35-44 Years"
        ]
      ],
      "Jun-20": [
        [
          "Jun-20",
          "002004",
          "002004 - No Description",
          4,
          12,
          "35-44 Years"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
};
console.log(input);
const output = [
  [
    "002004",
    "002004 - No Description",
    21,
    4,
    25,
    8,
    3,
    10,
    4,
    12
  ]
]
```

The input is a grouped by data with 2 levels. I want it be flattened.  Now for every code it is grouped by an age band then a month. I want the 1st and 2nd index to come first and the rest all should be spread after that.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate thru input levels to get the 3rd and 4th value of each nested array?

Comment: Thanks deltazero. I can do that by adding loops but I want to know with ramda can I achieve it more functionally rather than imperatively

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the pattern to get the arrays of that json format but to receive an array of arrays, create a function that get the indexes 3 and 4 of each inner array and then flatten all the results to a new array, we can try this:

```js
const getIndexes3and4 = slice(3, 5)
const getIndexesAndFlatten = pipe(map(getIndexes3and4), flatten)
const input = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
console.log(getIndexesAndFlatten(input)) // ["d", "e", "d", "e", "d", "e"]
```

references: [slice](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#slice), [pipe](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe), [map](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map), [flatten](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten)

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla javascript

```js
const input =   {"002004": { "25-34 Years": { "Jul-20": [ [ "Jul-20", "002004", "002004 - No Description", 21, 4, "25-34 Years" ] ], "Jun-20": [ [ "Jun-20", "002004", "002004 - No Description", 25, 8, "25-34 Years" ] ] }, "35-44 Years": { "Jul-20": [ [ "Jul-20", "002004", "002004 - No Description", 3, 10, "35-44 Years" ] ], "Jun-20": [ [ "Jun-20", "002004", "002004 - No Description", 4, 12, "35-44 Years" ] ] } }};
function flatten(obj){
      return Object.entries(input).flatMap(o=>{
        neso=Object.values(o[1])
        arr=neso.flatMap(o=>Object.values(o).flat())
        n=arr.flatMap((o)=>[o[3],o[4]])
        des=arr.flatMap((d)=>[d[1],d[2]])
        set=new Set(des)
         return [...set,...n]
      })
}
console.log(flatten(input))
```